# Mysql JOIN a select statement

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to limit the number of rows that are retrieved from a JOIN statement.

Considering these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `conversation` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `creator_id` INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`creator_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `message` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `body` VARCHAR(4096) NOT NULL,
    `date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `sender_id` INT,
    `receiver_id` INT,
    `conversation_id` INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
    FOREIGN KEY (`sender_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`receiver_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`conversation_id`) REFERENCES `conversation` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I would like to get the N last messages from the 20 last conversations  involving a specific user (let say the one with the id 42)

So my first idea would be to do this:

```
SELECT * FROM `conversation` `c`
LEFT JOIN `user` `u` ON `u`.`id` = `c`.`creator_id`
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM `message`
    LIMIT @N
    ORDER BY `date` DESC
) `m` ON `m`.`conversation_id` = `c`.`id`
WHERE `c`.`creator_id` = 42
LIMIT 20;
```

Since MySQL may create a temporary table `m` for each conversation, I'm just wondering how efficient this is or is there a better way to achieve the same result. Knowing that tables message and conversation may contain a huge amount of rows, I just don't want to limit the number of message rows client-side.

Answer (score 0):

- `@N` cannot be used in `LIMIT`.  (Use a constant.)
- `ORDER BY` must precede `LIMIT`.
- Don't use `LEFT` unless you really need it.  The optimizer would prefer to start with the subquery.
- `message` needs `INDEX(date)`; without it, it has to do a slow table scan.

Please explain what you want the query to do; I have not figured it out.